# rvest: filter nodes based on subsequent node

Tags: beautifulsoup, rvest

I'm trying to scrape links from a webpage. The webpage has hyperlinked images and hyperlinked `h3` headers. I want to discard the links for the images. Unfortunately, there are no classes, ids, or attributes of the `div`s to identify the image hyperlinks. Is there some logic in `rvest` or `bs4` to filter out the links based on the subsequently nested HTML elements? For example, if the next element is a `img` then ignore, if the next element is a `h3` then keep?

```
html <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" style="max-width:72px;max-height:72px">
        </a>
    </div>
      <span>
          <h3>
             <div>
                 Smiley Face
             </div>
          </h3>
      </span>
      <span>
          <div>
              https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png
          </div>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.hbs.edu">
            <h3>
                <div>Harvard Business School</div>
            </h3>
            <div>https://www.hbs.edu</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'

my_page <- read_html(html)
my_page %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

# [1] "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" # Want to ignore this
# [2] "https://www.hbs.edu" # Want to keep this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **rvest** you might wish to use xpath (parent axis) so as to specify the parent child (anchor tag h3 tag) relationship as follows:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

html <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" style="max-width:72px;max-height:72px">
        </a>
    </div>
      <span>
          <h3>
             <div>
                 Smiley Face
             </div>
          </h3>
      </span>
      <span>
          <div>
              https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png
          </div>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.hbs.edu">
            <h3>
                <div>Harvard Business School</div>
            </h3>
            <div>https://www.hbs.edu</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'

my_page <- read_html(html)
my_page %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "//h3/parent::a[@href]") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

---

With **bs4** you can use :has pseudo class selector with > child combinator to specify relationship of anchor tag with direct child h3 element. You can swop the child combinator for a descendant combinator if can be any child and not a direct child (potential difference in DOM depth)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html =  '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" style="max-width:72px;max-height:72px">
        </a>
    </div>
      <span>
          <h3>
             <div>
                 Smiley Face
             </div>
          </h3>
      </span>
      <span>
          <div>
              https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png
          </div>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.hbs.edu">
            <h3>
                <div>Harvard Business School</div>
            </h3>
            <div>https://www.hbs.edu</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # pip install lxml if missing
print([i['href'] for i in soup.select('a[href]:has(> h3)')])
```

---

In either case, I have specified that the parent anchor tag must have an href attribute.